# Set one kind of enum to another enum kind of enum in java

Tags: java, enums

I have identical enums defined in both an entity class as well as in a response class. I want to set the value of an enum property in one of the classes to an enum property from the other class. Below is sample code.  I am very new to Java and the IT industry.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class ResponseClass{
    enum Type{
        USD, CSD, MXN, BRL;
    };
    
    private Type type;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class EntityClass{
    enum Type{
        USD, CSD, MXN, BRL;
    };
    
    @Column(name = "type")
    private Type type;
}
```

```java
public class Main{
    public static void main(){
        EntityClass entity= new EntityClass();
        
        ResponseClass response = ...; //Got value for this variable from REST API
        
        entity.setType(response.getType()); // I want to achive this
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally better to post code as text here, rather than as an image.

Comment: Please don't post (just) pictures of code. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you declare `enum Type` out of `Entity` or `Response` class. Then you could use same enum for both classes.

You can declare an enum at any of three levels:

- Separate class
- Nested within a class
- Locally ([in Java 16+](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395))

For your situation, I suggest you use the first rather than the second.